# Actual And Expected values are same but unit test fails. Why?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, assert

I am trying to learn unit test on VS 2012 and tried this:

```
 public class Calculator
 {
    public double substraction(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
 }
```

and My test class is here:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void calc_substract()
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        Assert.AreEqual<double>(calculator.substraction(5.3, 1.1), 4.2);
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

```
Test Name:  calc_substract
Test FullName:  MyUnitTest.UnitTest1.calc_substract
Test Source:    d:\Users\...
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,0068363

**Result Message:   Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<4,2>. Actual:<4,2>.**
```

As you see, values are same but test fails. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very odd, I'm wondering if it's a loss of precision issue since you're working with doubles - although the values seem innocuous enough not to trigger precision issues.

Also, fantastic result message :).

Does it at least pass if you ask it to compare 4.2 to 4.2:

```
Assert.AreEqual<double>(4.2, 4.2);
```

?

Would also be curious to see what happens if you plug in some rounding:

```
Assert.AreEqual<double>(Math.Round(calculator.substraction(5.3, 1.1),1), 4.2);
```

Also, consider using `decimal` instead of `double` as it has greater precision and more naturally represents exact decimals, so you should find precision issues with cases like your specific test are avoided with `decimal` - although that's not to say other, more complex cases, won't still suffer from precision issues even with `decimal`

Comment: after trying Math.Round() test passed! but why? there should be no decimal substracting 1.1 from 5.3.. anyway thanks!

Comment: You always run the risk of having precision issues with floating point calculations.